# How is the die for Cat Tower configured?

Tags: dice, cat-tower

I just bought Cat Tower yesterday and the die came unlabeled with the stickers to be applied to each of the 6 faces. Unfortunately, it gave no indication as to how to apply the stickers.  Based upon a picture on the box, I was able to apply 3 of the faces, but am stuck on the remaining 3 faces.  Is there any indication as to how the faces should be arranged (for example I might guess the 2 one cat faces might be on opposite faces of the die).

Pictures or instructions appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A comment from the publisher on their [Kickstarter page](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/idwgames/cat-tower/comments) answers your question perfectly:

[image]

This is their answer, but I'm also seeing complaints about unevenly shaped dice. If this is the case for your game, you should try to get your dice replaced.

If you can't get your dice replaced, make sure you **don't** put duplicates on opposing faces. You want **dis**similar vales to oppose each other (eg 2 and 5 on a 1d6) to negate the effect of having [a flattened dice](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/13408/10113).

Comment: DareMachina seemed to have the same sense of me as to put the duplicate label on opposite faces, but yes thank you for the definitive answer from the creator.

Comment: And yes, I have heard others mention that the die might not give 1/6 results for each face due to the manufacture of the die, so I will see how it goes

Comment: @demongolem I'm not too familiar with the sides of the dice but duplicates on opposite faces sounds like a bad idea if the dice is flat. If a 1d6 is flat, a possible result could be that both 1 and 6 would be rolled less often and this would not affect the average outcome. If you put identical images on opposing sides, this will double any effect you get from having an uneven dice.

Answer (score 4):

As long as the die isn't poorly manufactured, the propablility to roll any given side is close (for a perfect die - identical) to 1/6. The actual placement of faces changes nothing.